# Having problems with linear pytorch model initialization

Tags: python, deep-learning, neural-network, pytorch, initialization

I am trying to figure out what is wrong with my initialization of the neural network model. I have already set a pdb trace to see that the defining neural network part is the source of error. Also, I get yellow marks on the defining neural network code because the module is expected to be returned but if I return the module, it causes a recursion error. It is a linear model that has to have an input dimension of the batch size * 81 and an output dimension of the batch size * 1. I am relatively new at pytorch and defining deep neural networks so this may not be a good question. My syntax may also be very bad. Any help is appreciated. The code below is the defining of the neural network and training of the pytorch model.

```
def get_nnet_model(module_list=nn.ModuleList(), input_dim: int = 8100, layer_dim: int = 100) -> nn.Module:
    """ Get the neural network model
    @return: neural network model
    """
    device = torch.device('cpu')

    module_list.append(nn.Linear(input_dim, layer_dim))
    module_list[-1].weight.data.normal_(0, 0.1)
    module_list[-1].bias.data.zero_()


def train_nnet(nnet: nn.Module, states_nnet: np.ndarray, outputs: np.ndarray, batch_size: int = 100, num_itrs: int = 10000, train_itr: int = 10000, device: torch.device, lr=0.01, lr_d=1):
    nnet.train()

    criterion = nn.MSELoss()
    optimizer = optim.Adam(nnet.parameters(), lr=lr)

    while train_itr < num_itrs:
        optimizer.zero_grad()

        lr_itr = lr + (lr_d ** train_itr)
        for param_group in optimizer.param_groups:
            param_group['lr'] = lr_itr

        data = pickle.load(open("data/data.pkl", "rb"))
        nnet_inputs_np, nnet_targets_np = data
        nnet_inputs_np = nnet_inputs_np.astype(np.float32)

        nnet_inputs = torch.tensor(nnet_inputs_np, device=device)
        nnet_targets = torch.tensor(nnet_targets_np, device=device)

        nnet_inputs = nnet_inputs.float()
        nnet_outputs = nnet(nnet_inputs)

        loss = criterion(nnet_outputs, nnet_targets)
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Any error message? If so, update with the complete traceback.

Comment: I have completed a traceback and the problem is the definition of get_nnet_model. I am not sure what is specifically causing the problem but somewhere within that part is not working. When I run the code, using nnet.train() in main, it says that there is "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'train'"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your comment, somewhere else in your code you have something like:

```py
nnet = get_nnet_model(...)
```

However, `get_nnet_model(...)` isn't returning anything. Change the `def get_nnet_model` to:

```py
def get_nnet_model(module_list=nn.ModuleList(), input_dim: int = 8100, layer_dim: int = 100) -> nn.Module:
    """ Get the neural network model
    @return: neural network model
    """
    device = torch.device('cpu')

    module_list.append(nn.Linear(input_dim, layer_dim))
    module_list[-1].weight.data.normal_(0, 0.1)
    module_list[-1].bias.data.zero_()

    return module_list  # add this one
```

Comment: Oh you're definitely right. I completely forget to add that return at the end. Silly mistake there, my bad. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Don't worry @growt, it happens to everyone :) In the next question, try to always provide the error message together with the traceback. It helps people that are trying to help you.